# How to add a folder or file in Windows Defender Exclusions programmatically?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

There is this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233123/windows-defender-add-exclusion-folder-programmatically) but it is outdated since it is 4 years old and things have changed. It doesn't work anymore. Do you guys know any updated solution?

Comment: how about Powershell? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/add-mppreference?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Comment: *"It doesn't work anymore."* - Unfortunately, this doesn't say anything  about the problem you're encountering.

Comment: @FrankThomas please do that as an answer, i think it solves it just i haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @Anaksunaman actually it does. It means that the solution provided doesn't work anymore because of 1 or 2 reasons. So the other more knowledgeable people can elaborate if that's true or not.

Comment: @thecowmilk: Well, your text still does not document the way it doesn't work, it doesn't provide any error details. I think that's what Anaksunaman meant. BTW, for me the Power Shell command provided in the answers from your original URL works just fine – just tested on w10 [10.0.19044.2965].